# Sql query for joining data of two table with SUM and order by clause

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I have two tables in my database. `tbl_Transaction_Detail` and `tbl_Categrory_Type`. `tbl_Transaction_Detail` uses `Category_Type_ID` of `tbl_Category_Type` as foreign key. here is my tables:

[image: tbl_Category_Type]

[image: tbl_Transaction_Detail]

i want to SUM the `Quantity` of `tbl_Transaction_Detail` for the `Category_Type_ID` (say 31) .

here is my query for this (in sql server 2008)

```
SELECT CAT.Category_type_Name,
CAT.Description,
CAT.Image_url,
CAT.Price,
CAT.Weight,
Sum(TD.Quantity)'Quantity' from tbl_Transaction_Detail as TD 
inner join tbl_Category_type as CAT 
on TD .Category_Type_ID= CAT.Category_type_ID 
WHERE TD.Category_Type_ID = 31
ORDER BY CAT.Category_type_Name,
CAT.Description,
CAT.Image_url,
CAT.Price,
CAT.Weight
```

but it shows error for all column selection one by one.

Comment: You need a group by in SQL server.  mySQl doesn't require it due to it's extended group by. add `GROUP BY tbl_Category_type.Category_type_Name,tbl_Category_type.Description,tbl_Category_type.Image_url
      ,tbl_Category_type.Price,tbl_Category_type.Weight`  and for readability, use table aliases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use group by clause, Include each column in group by clause which you want to select except the column for which you are using aggregate function. Kindly use table aliases for  better readability.

```
  SELECT CAT.Category_type_Name
  ,CAT.Description
  ,CAT.Image_url
  ,CAT.Price
  ,CAT.Weight
  ,Sum(TD.Quantity) as Quantity
  FROM tbl_Transaction_Detail TD
  INNER JOIN tbl_Category_type CAT
  on TD.Category_Type_ID=CAT.Category_type_ID 
  WHERE TD.Category_Type_ID=31 
  GROUP BY CAT.Category_type_Name
  ,CAT.Description
  ,CAT.Image_url
  ,CAT.Price
  ,CAT.Weight
  ORDER BY CAT.Category_type_Name
  ,CAT.Description
  ,CAT.Image_url
  ,CAT.Price
  ,CAT.Weight
```

Comment: can u suggest me any way of selecting an **int** column in select clause and multiply its value by 1 then bind it to gridview

Comment: You don't need to muliply any int value with 1 as answer will remain same after multipcation with 1. But incase you want to multiply an int column with any number then you SQL query will look like this
    **Select (intColumn * number) as name From table**

Answer (score 1):

Just missing a group by for SQL server.... and use table aliases for readability and spacing!

```
select CT.Category_type_Name
      ,CT.Description
      ,CT.Image_url
      ,CT.Price
      ,CT.Weight
      ,Sum(TD.Quantity) as Quantity
FROM tbl_Transaction_Detail TD
INNER JOIN tbl_Category_type CT
  on TD.Category_Type_ID=CT.Category_type_ID 
WHERE TD.Category_Type_ID=31 
GROUP BY CT.Category_type_Name
        ,CT.Description
        ,CT.Image_url
        ,CT.Price
        ,CT.Weight
ORDER BY CT.Category_type_Name
        ,CT.Description
        ,CT.Image_url
        ,CT.Price
        ,CT.Weight
```